# View with reference entity type

Tags: views, 10

I have a View entity reference type and I want to get the fields along with fields I m using relationship Field to cal referenced type entities

I have content type with name product
Field 1: title
Field 2: description
Field 3: listing & it's a paragraph entity refenced field

I created a View and called fiels
But Field 3 contain multiple fields

But saw the title & description fields repeated number of time entity type refenced occurs

Let say 1 have 10 node

Node:1

Title 1
Description 1
Listing 1

Title 1
Description 1
Listing 2

Title 1
Description 1
Listing 3

Node:2

Title 2
Description 2
Listing 1

Title 2
Description 2
Listing 2

........ 10

Now I want

Title 1
Description 1
Listing 1
Listing 2
Listing 3

Title 2
Description 2
Listing 1
Listing 2
........

Answer (score 0):

Select "Unformatted list" as your format. You can then use "Grouping fields" under the settings to group by both the title and description. You may need to play with CSS and/or Twig to get the exact output you want.